# Is there a way i can use the existing instance (object) of the class

Tags: java, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have a class implemented as below

```
@Builder
class A extends B {

   @Getter
   public List<Customer> cusromers = new ArrayList<>();

   @Override
   public void add(){
     c.add(obj);
   }

}
```

Below is in different project

```java
class C {
    public Student<T, C> getValues() {
        return A.builder().customers(getCustomers()).build()
    }
}
```

The below is different project and has dependency of the above's project

```
@Test
class Test {
   // I need to check the instance of class A and test if the instance has added some modifications for the list above stated class
}
```

Please any one help me on this. Excuse me if i do any mistake

Comment: This might not compile, where does `obj` come from ?

Comment: obj is input, i just wrote for example. didn't passed exact one which i am passed in my code

Comment: please any help mush appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotation in combination with your `@Builder`.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
class A extends B {

   public List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

   @Override
   public void add(){
     customers.add(new Customer());
   }

}

@Test
class Test {
    A a = new A():
    List<Customer> customers = a.getCustomers();
    assertEquals(1, customers.size());
}
```

Comment: when we do A a = new A(), it will create new new instance i want to get values from previous instance which is created and setted some values in some other class. please see my updated question

Comment: please help on this, just direct me as i am beginner to lombok. i have idea about to singleton implementation but with lombok how i need to make is matter here. can you please help